# when linking with "ld" am getting following error?

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, linker, ld

Am getting following error when doing linking.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfl

======
cc -g .//obj/add.o .//obj/append.o .//obj/check.o .//obj/compare.o .//obj/free_mem.o
.//obj/output.o .//obj/postmosy.o .//obj/premosyy.o .//obj/premosyl.o .//obj/process.o
.//obj/store.o -o v2comp -lfl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfl
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [v2comp] Error 1
```

thanks
Rajesh kumar V

Comment: It doesn't know what the "fl" library is. Make sure you put `-L\location\to\.so`

Comment: ...propbably because that library is not installed, at least not in one of the directories in the linker search path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help:

```
sudo apt-get install libfl-dev
```